# How to import a private Go library (as module) within another private Go project (as module)

Tags: git, go, gitlab, go-modules

I am moving a few private Go projects to GitLab while getting rid of `Godeps`, Go `dep` with `vendor` directory and all of that because I would like to use just Go modules.

I am using Go version: `go1.12.6 linux/amd64`.

- I have a private "library" project / git repository at `gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library`. This works as a Go module with `go.mod` and `go.sum`.
- I would like to use `my-library` as a dependency for another project, this: `gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-project`.

The structure of the URL is the same, the only thing that changes is the name of the repository.

I am facing all sorts of errors while importing `my-library` in `my-project`.

- How can I import Go modules as private repositories inside other Go modules as private repositories?
- What's wrong with the command outputs below?

I know the GitLab tokens work because the `go get` command figures out itself the commit ID of `my-library`. Anyway I've done the following (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html):

```
git config \
  --global \
  url."https://token_name:token_val@gitlab.com".insteadOf \
  "https://gitlab.com"
```

These are the error messages:

```sh
$ go get -u gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library.git
go: finding gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library.git latest
go: gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library.git@v0.0.0-20190802120216-712a10fb5fac: parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library"
go get: error loading module requirements
$ 
$ go get -u gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library
go get gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library: git ls-remote -q https://gitlab.com/my-company/my-team.git in /home/foo/Development/go-workspace/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/9be637426eac43b329899d57d9375d12246f2cc0f6ddd098446bc42ed1ca534d: exit status 128:
    remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
    fatal: repository 'https://token_name:token_val@gitlab.com/my-company/my-team.git/' not found
$ 
$ GO111MODULE=off go get -u gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library.git
package gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library.git: no Go files in /home/foo/Development/go-workspace/src/gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library.git
$
```

- The first attempt is the one I think I should use, but it does not work and I don't know why.

  - I thought this was happening because somehow there was already a dependency like this in the project. But when executing `go mod graph | grep gitlab` I find an empty output, i.e. there is no conflicting dependency.
- The second attempt is probably to be avoided because the URL does not end with `.git` and (for some reason that I don't understand) the URL is cut at the level of `my-team`.
- `GO111MODULE=off` seems to force `go get` to check in `$GOPATH` which I think I should avoid at all, but I was just trying to see if that way I was able to fetch that dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely suggest trying with Go 1.13 beta:

```
$ go get golang.org/dl/go1.13beta1
$ go1.13beta1 download
$ go1.13beta1 get foo
```

or even better, try the latest Go on tip / master (given the Go 1.13 beta1 release is over a month old at this point):

```
$ go get golang.org/dl/gotip
$ gotip download
$ gotip get foo
```

Go 1.13 improved several aspects of working with private repositories (including [CL 170879](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/170879/) among other improvements), and also it generally has better error messages compared to Go 1.12.

For your first error message:

```
$ go get -u gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library.git
go: finding gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library.git latest
go: gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library.git@v0.0.0-20190802120216-712a10fb5fac:
 parsing go.mod: unexpected module path "gitlab.com/my-company/my-team/my-library"
go get: error loading module requirements
```

That is the `go` command complaining about a mismatch between how a module is imported/required, vs. how it declares its own identity in the `module` line of its `go.mod`.  If module `foo` is importing module `bar`, then `foo` needs to refer to `bar` the same way that `bar` declares its identity on the the `module` line of `bar`'s `go.mod` file.

Said another way, the import path used to import a module (or `go get` a module) needs to start with the exact module path declared on the `module` line of the imported module's `go.mod`. You might need to change the importer to match the form declared on the `module` line in the `go.mod` file, or you might need to change the `module` line in the `go.mod` to match the form used by the importer, but they can't disagree. If they disagree, you get the first error you reported.

In general, you have a few choices about how to use private repos with Go modules. These two blog posts outline several of the issues and cover a few approaches, and are well worth a read if you haven't read them:

- ["Fetching Private Dependencies with Go Modules"](https://medium.com/@tim_raymond/fetching-private-dependencies-with-go-modules-1d65afe47c62), by Tim Raymond
- ["Go Modules with Private Git Repositories"](https://medium.com/cloud-native-the-gathering/go-modules-with-private-git-repositories-dfe795068db4), by Tim Jones

Finally, if it is still not clear what is going on, you probably should try `go get -v foo` or `go get -v -x foo`:

- The `-v` flag to `go get` asks to print more verbose details, including the [HTTPS requests](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths), though be mindful that certain "errors" such as 404 errors might be expected based on how a remote repository was configured.
- If the nature of the problem is still not clear, you can also try the more verbose `go get -v -x foo`, which also shows the git or other VCS commands being issued. If warranted, you can often execute the same git commands outside of the context of the `go` tool for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Difference in my go.mod file vs what I was trying to import was my issue! Far too much Googling to find this answer with that nugget...

Answer (score 1):

1. If the building server has no access to the internet, we need a private "nexus3 goproxy".

```
export GOPROXY=http://nexus.my-company.com/nexus/repository/goproxy/,direct
export GONOPROXY=gitlab.my-company.com
export GOSUMDB=off
export GO111MODULE=on
```

2. Forbid trying to download through http(s) protocol

even if "gitlab.my-company.com" does not support https, just config like this:

```
git config --global url."git@gitlab.my-company.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.my-company.com/"
```

3. Because of gitlab's flaw, we need to replace the module download path in go.mod config

```
require (
    gitlab.my-company.com/my-team/my-library v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
)

replace (
    #use "go get -insecure gitlab.my-company.com/my-team/my-library" to get latest commit hash
    gitlab.my-company.com/my-team/my-library => git.midea.com/my-team/my-library.git v0.0.0-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYYY
)
```