# Module name works improperly

Tags: go, go-modules

There is a private git site with address of `gitlab.myownsite.com`, and the folder structure in the way of:

```
/common
    |___ /libs
           |___ /lib_a
                  |__ lib_a.mod
/somethingelse
```

Notice that, this is NOT folder structure of single project, it is structure of `gitlab.myownsite.com`, which contain many repo in it. For example, I write a library `lib_a` by Go, then create a repo at path `gitlab.myownsite.com/common/libs/lib_a`, and its module name is:

```
module gitlab.myownsite.com/common/libs/lib_a
```

However, this naming disobeys the naming rule of `github.com/username/reponame`, which cause another project which use my lib_a by:

```
import "gitlab.myownsite.com/common/libs/lib_a"
```

incorrectly parse to import subpackage lib_a of gitlab.myownsite.com/common/libs.git, the `common` be recognized as `username`, libs as `reponame`, lib_a as packagename. go mod report error:

```
repository 'https://gitlab.myownsite.com/common/libs.git/' not found
```

I can not change the folder structure of this private gitlab site, how to solve this problem?

My go module env has: GOPRIVATE=gitlab.myownsite.com

Comment: Do you have multiple modules? Where is the `go.mod` file?

Comment: this gitlab is shared with many people. lib_x is independent project, however, they have same parent folder

Comment: What are `lib_a.mod` and `lib_b.mod`? How do they relate to your Go code? Did you mean to put `go.mod` files in these locations, or is that something else?

Comment: I'm not sure if your comment was meant to address @icza's question, but it doesn't. Do you have multiple modules? Where is the `go.mod` file?

Comment: It's very unclear what problem you're trying to solve, but it may be related to GitLab subgroups limitations in private repos. There are some workarounds discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56817601/13860) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29707689/13860).

Comment: I redescribe my problem, hope that won't bring confusion

Comment: Make sure your gitlab provides the necessary and relevant  import meta headers. Read https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths. Note that your assumtion that there is some kind of "naming rule of github.com/username/reponame" is plain wrong. There is no such thing. Some codehosting sites are known to the go tool, all other (especially yout  Gitlab instance) has to provide the `<meta name="go-import" content="example.org git https://code.org/r/p/exproj">` response. No need to change any folder layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @[Volker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266756/volker) to point out, there is a meta info responsed when go get execute which describe which part of path is repo (the `.git`). Unfortunately, gitlab has [a bug on it](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/36354). I'm search a [replace trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58338553/851185) can avoid this problem. Or, last resort, re-structure gitlab path